# Multiple after UPDATE triggers on a SQL Server 2008 table, one of which updates that selfsame table

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

An `after-update` trigger on a table updates that very table:

```
TRG_FOO_AFTER_UPDATE updates FOO
```

There is a second after-update trigger on the same table:

```
TRG_FOO_AFTER_UPDATE2
```

The second writes a row out to an audit table. Does the second trigger fire twice?

Comment: If I were to answer this question, I would most likely establish the answer by conducting a test. In my estimation, that would be a matter of several minutes, half hour at most. My point is, you could have done that yourself without having to wait for an answer all these nearly 5 hours.

Comment: Here's my modus operandi, Andriy: look for documentation on the question; if I cannot find it, ask here, with the intention of doing the very tests you suggest; however, in case there's a "wrinkle" and my tests didn't test for every possible combination of possibilities, it's also good to ask people who have run into this. This is my first time working with SQL 2008--coming directly from SQL 2000.

Comment: So, what's the answer?  If someone would have just answered this, my simple google search would save me that half hour it takes to actually test it myself.  I believe the answer depends on if you have recursive triggers enabled or not, but I'm not sure if the second trigger counts as a recursive trigger.  If I have time to test it, I'll answer it myself I guess.